# Regex capture groups with specific word

Tags: regex, regex-group

**Sample text:**

```
begin
more text 
art
  id:213213
  code:"XXX"
  name:234
art-
art
  id:543
  name:72
  code:"AAA"
art-
art
  code:"XXX"
  id:32
  name:46
art-
art
  code:"CCC"
  id:8765
art-
art
  id:876
  code:"DDD"
art-
even more text
even more text
end
```

**Target:**

Trying to get the groups starting with `art` ending with `art-` where the group contains `"XXX"` .

So i want

```
art
  id:213213
  code:"XXX"
  name:234
art-
```

and

```
art
  code:"XXX"
  id:32
  name:46
art-
```

Started with [regex101](https://regex101.com/) but did not get far.

Tried:

```
(?sm)(.*?)(?:art.*?art-)(.*?)
```

And

```
(?sm)(.*?)(?:art.*?"XXX".*?art-)(.*?)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

We can do it using **[Tempered Greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/5331061)**. Try this regex:

```
art(?:(?!art-)[\s\S])*code:"XXX"(?:(?!art-)[\s\S])*art-
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lVdj1o/1)**

**Expanation:**

- `art` - matches `art`
- `(?:(?!art-)[\s\S])*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character which is not starting with text `art-`. In short, it matches anything until it finds next occurrence of `art-`
- `code:"XXX"` - matches `code:"XXX"`
- `(?:(?!art-)[\s\S])*` - again matches 0+ occurrences of any character which is not starting with text `art-`
- `art-` - matches `art-`

Comment: @Dennis Any reason for un-accepting this answer after accepting it?

Answer (score 1):

You can match all lines that do not start with `art-` or contain `code:"XXX:` and then match the specific line.

This will

```
^art(?:\r?\n(?!art-|\s*code:"XXX").*)*\r?\n\s*code:"XXX"(?:\r?\n(?!art-).*)*\r?\nart-
```

The pattern matches

- `^` Start of string
- `art` Match art
- `(?:\r?\n(?!art-|\s*code:"XXX").*)*` Match all lines that do not start with `art-` or contain `code:"XXX"`
- `\r?\n\s*code:"XXX"` Match a newline and match the line with `code:"XXX"`
- `(?:\r?\n(?!art-).*)*` Continue matching all lines that do not start with `art-`
- `\r?\nart-` Match a newline and `art-`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zWXbGh/1)

There is no language tagged, but for example with JavaScript

```js
const regex = /^art(?:\r?\n(?!art-|\s*code:"XXX").*)*\r?\n\s*code:"XXX"(?:\r?\n(?!art-).*)*\r?\nart-/gm;
const str = `begin
more text 
art
  id:213213
  code:"XXX"
  name:234
art-
art
  id:543
  name:72
  code:"AAA"
art-
art
  code:"XXX"
  id:32
  name:46
art-
art
  code:"CCC"
  id:8765
art-
art
  id:876
  code:"DDD"
art-
even more text
even more text
end`;
let m;

console.log(str.match(regex));
```